# Need to completely export a Docker image from a system to another system, how to find volumes to export data?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-image

I am trying to export an entire Docker container into an image that have to be run on a second system. Also the data (the volumes) must be exported. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QskmB4fb-uo) but I am finding some difficulties trying to retrieve and export my volumes.

I inspected the Docker container that I want to export, in order to retrieve volumes information:

```
sudo docker inspect postgresql
```

I searched for the **Mounts** section in the output in order to find where my volumes should be, I obtained this:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "spring-microservies-course_psdb-volume",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/spring-microservies-course_psdb-volume/_data",
        "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "rw",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

So I suppose that my volumes should be in the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/spring-microservies-course_psdb-volume/_data` directory.

The problem is that this is what I have into this folder:

```
andrea@ubuntu:/var/lib$ sudo ls -a /var/lib/docker/volumes/spring-microservies-course_psdb-volume/_data
.   base    pg_commit_ts  pg_hba.conf    pg_logical    pg_notify    pg_serial     pg_stat      pg_subtrans  pg_twophase  pg_wal   postgresql.auto.conf  postmaster.opts
..  global  pg_dynshmem   pg_ident.conf  pg_multixact  pg_replslot  pg_snapshots  pg_stat_tmp  pg_tblspc    PG_VERSION   pg_xact  postgresql.conf
```

So where are the volumes that I have to export together with the container image in order to have my data?

Comment: That _is_ the data. The volume is mounting your local directory into the container.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so have I to export all this directory "/var/lib/docker/volumes/spring-microservies-course_psdb-volume/_data" to put restore data when I migrate an image to a different machine?

Comment: Via the same docs I linked on your previous question: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would think about is to create a new docker image from my running container and copy the content I need from that container, try to follow these steps:

Create a docker image based on the container you are working with:

```
docker commit <image_name> <new_image_name>
```

Copy the content you want to get from the running container (make sure you are running this command as administrator/root:

```
docker cp <image_name>:<directory_path_inside_container> <directory_path_on_your_machine>
```

Make sure you are logged in:

```
docker login
```

Push the newly created image to your docker repository (don't forget to create one):

```
docker push <new_image_name>
```

Once you complete pushing go to your other system and pull the image

```
docker pull <new_image_name>
```

> It would be better if you specify the image tag and version within your docker image name.

Now that you got both your image and the data you needed simply copy the data to your new system, run your new image with using bind mount with your data.

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice and I would not recommend it.  It will also not meet this questioner's needs, since committing a container doesn't include any data in volumes or bind mounts; committing a database container does not include its data.  You should think of your container like a _process_ you can stop with `^C` and run again; anything that was in local storage when the container exits is lost, but you can rebuild a new binary from the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I have included  `docker cp` with `docker commit`  in the commands which will allow him to copy the content needed and the configuration of the container, and as I said he could copy his data saved on his machine with the `docker cp`  command either using a `Dockerfile` using `COPY`  or a `bind mount volume`  when running container.